# ENOTFOUND on NodeJS server to Redis with Docker

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, redis, docker-compose

So I'm trying to put my server and the databases into docker containers using docker-compose.

The docker-compose file that I currently have looks like:

```
version: "2"
services:
  api:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command: npm run-script docker
    networks:
      - backend

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - backend

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
```

My code that connects to the databses looks like:

```
/**
 * Init the Redis db.
 * @returns {*|Promise}
 */
init: function (isMaster=false) {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        logger.logInfo('(rdb.init) Trying to connect to Redis database');
        client = redis.createClient("redis://redis:6379");

        client.on("error", err => {
            logger.logFatal('(rdb.init) Could not connect to redis database - ' + err);
            reject(err);
        });

        client.on("connect", () => {
            logger.logInfo('(rdb.init) Successfully connected to redis database');

            if (config.CLEAR_REDIS_COLLECTIONS && isMaster) {
                logger.logWarn('(rdb.init) CLEAR_REDIS_COLLECTIONS = ' + config.CLEAR_REDIS_COLLECTIONS);
                dropCollections().then(() => resolve()).catch(err => reject(err));
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

And

```
/*
 *Connect to the database
 */
function init(isMaster=false) {

    logger.logInfo('(mdb.init) Trying to connect to the database @' + config.DB_URL);

    mongoose.Promise = Promise;

    // Connect to the db
    return mongoose.connect("mongodb://mongodb:27017/stuber", {useMongoClient: true}).then(() => {
        logger.logInfo('(mdb.init) Successfully connected to the database');

        if (config.CLEAR_MONGO_COLLECTIONS && isMaster) {
            logger.logWarn('(mdb.init) CLEAR_MONGO_COLLECTIONS = ' + config.CLEAR_MONGO_COLLECTIONS);
            return dropCollections();
        } else {
            return Promise.resolve();
        }
    }, err => {
        logger.logFatal('(mdb.init) Could not connect to the database - ' + err);
        return Promise.reject(err);
    });
}
```

The logs that I'm getting from the server before it crashes is:

> api_1      | [2017-12-29 14:25:36.711] [INFO] Stuber - [Master] ==================================| v0.4.0 |==================================
>   api_1      | [2017-12-29 14:25:36.770] [WARN] Stuber - [Master] (tokenAuth) Token authentication BYPASS = false
>   api_1      | [2017-12-29 14:25:38.594] [INFO] Stuber - [Master] (io.createImageDirs) User image path = /app/public/images/users/
>   api_1      | [2017-12-29 14:25:38.595] [INFO] Stuber - [Master] (io.createImageDirs) Vehicle image path = /app/public/images/vehicles/
>   api_1      | [2017-12-29 14:25:38.595] [INFO] Stuber - [Master] (io.createImageDirs) Creating "public" directory
>   api_1      | [2017-12-29 14:25:38.596] [INFO] Stuber - [Master] (io.createImageDirs) Creating "images" directory
>   api_1      | [2017-12-29 14:25:38.596] [INFO] Stuber - [Master] (io.createImageDirs) Creating "users" directory
>   api_1      | [2017-12-29 14:25:38.597] [INFO] Stuber - [Master] (io.createImageDirs) Creating "vehicles" directory
>   api_1      | [2017-12-29 14:25:38.597] [INFO] Stuber - [Master] (rdb.init) Trying to connect to Redis database
>   api_1      | [2017-12-29 14:25:38.682] [INFO] Stuber - [Master] (rdb.init) Successfully connected to redis database
>   api_1      | [2017-12-29 14:25:38.682] [WARN] Stuber - [Master] (rdb.init) CLEAR_REDIS_COLLECTIONS = true
>   api_1      | [2017-12-29 14:25:38.781] [INFO] Stuber - [Master] (rdb.dropCollections) Cleared Redis database
>   api_1      | [2017-12-29 14:25:38.782] [INFO] Stuber - [Master] (mdb.init) Trying to connect to the database @mongodb://user:xxx@xxx:xxx/stuber
>   mongodb_1  | 2017-12-29T14:25:38.808+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.19.0.2:33810 #2 (1 connection now open)
>   mongodb_1  | 2017-12-29T14:25:38.834+0000 I NETWORK  [conn2] received client metadata from 172.19.0.2:33810 conn: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "2.2.33" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.4.0-1039-aws" }, platform: "Node.js v7.10.1, LE, mongodb-core: 2.1.17" }
>   api_1      | [2017-12-29 14:25:38.847] [INFO] Stuber - [Master] (mdb.init) Successfully connected to the database
>   api_1      | [2017-12-29 14:25:38.847] [INFO] Stuber - [Master] (server) Create kue job queues
>   api_1      | [2017-12-29 14:25:38.934] [INFO] Stuber - [Master] (kue.init) Master worker is being assigned processing of jobs
>   api_1      | [2017-12-29 14:25:38.947] [INFO] Stuber - [Master] (server.init) Retrieving all system IDs from database
>   api_1      | poop
>   api_1      | events.js:163
>   api_1      |       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>   api_1      |       ^
>   api_1      |
>   api_1      | Error: Redis connection to redis://redis:6379 failed - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND redis://redis redis://redis:6379
>   api_1      |     at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
>   api_1      |     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:73:26)

Ignore **[2017-12-29 14:25:38.782] [INFO] Stuber - [Master] (mdb.init) Trying to connect to the database @mongodb://user:xxx@xxx:xxx/stuber** as the it is not logging the correct address, the code shows what it is actually connecting to.

So according to the logs the server is able to connect to the Mongo and Redis database, but then it seems to lose connection to the Redis one for some reason. I have tried various premade docker-compose files that are intended for Node-Mongo-Redis setups but none have worked so far. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and this solved my issue maybe it can also help you.

```
$ npm info express --verbose
# Error message: npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: 
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
$ nslookup registry.npmjs.org
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
registry.npmjs.org  canonical name = a.sni.fastly.net.
a.sni.fastly.net    canonical name = prod.a.sni.global.fastlylb.net.
Name:   prod.a.sni.global.fastlylb.net
Address: 151.101.32.162
$ sudo vim /etc/hosts 
# Add "151.101.32.162 registry.npmjs.org` to hosts file
$ npm info express --verbose
# Works now!
```

Original Source: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6686